# Why is YAML.load returning the wrong numeric value?

Tags: ruby, yaml, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

Why is YAML.load returning the wrong value?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :006 > a = YAML.load('merchant_id: 014213245611111')
 => {"merchant_id"=>843333440073} 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :007 > a["merchant_id"]
 => 843333440073
```

I'm on ruby 1.9.2-p0, rvm, ubuntu10.10, 64bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The YAML parser is treating "014213245611111" as an octal (base-8) number, rather than a string. Wrap it in quotes to preserve the leading 0.

Answer (score 3):

A leading 0 signifies an octal number — 14213245611111 octal == 843333440073 decimal. If you need to have leading zeroes, you should use a string value instead of numeric.