# Why does YAML interpret '0777' as 511?

Tags: ruby, yaml

In my YAML file I have:

```
foo:
  - '0777'
```

When I load the file in my code (`result = YAML.load_file(...)`) I get

```
result[:foo] = [511]
```

This happens on Ubuntu. On Mac it is correct (`["0777"]`). When changed to:

```
foo:
  - "'0777'"
```

it works on Ubuntu but the string consists the quotes: `'0777'`.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is YAML.load returning the wrong numeric value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229919/why-is-yaml-load-returning-the-wrong-numeric-value)

Comment: Does your Ruby script do anything apart from load the YAML file ? How are you outputing the result?

Comment: @Wolfwyrd: No, in that question, there is an integer in the YAML document. Here, it is clearly a string that is somehow double-decoded as an integer. That has nothing to with the semantics of YAML, that's just simply a bug in the YAML decoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby for `Integer` if the argument is string, and happen to start with `0x`, `0b`, `0`, it is interpreted as hex, binary, octal string respectively.

Therefore here `0777` is being treated as an octal string. Since `'0777' octal = '511' decimal`, you are getting `511` as result.

[reference](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/function.html#Integer)

Comment: But isn't `'0777'` a string, not an integer?

Comment: How should I then put it in the .yml file to make it a string? `"'0777'"` is not a good idea because then I get the quotes in the string (`'0777'`), which I don't want (I want `0777`).

Comment: as per my understanding it should be treated as String if you put it in single quotes `''` as in your example. I can reproduce this issue only without `''`. However if that's not the case, you may try using double quotes `"0777"`. PS: to be honest I'm making wild guess here as I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Your difference probably isn't Ubuntu vs OSX, but different YAML gems/versions in use on the different computers. Make sure you are using the exact same version of ruby on both? My guess is you are running into a YAML bug on one of them, but have a newer version without the bug on the other.  YAML is kind of an nightmare sometimes with edge issues like these.

Comment: Well, the question is *why* is it treated as an octal integer when it is in fact a string? There must be some sort of double-decoding going on, where the YAML is decoded *twice*, once into a string and then the string is decoded again as an integer. That's clearly a bug.